# Why does my filewriter leave unnecessary lines when writing to the file?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, filewriter

I have a `filewriter` which (obviously) is being used to write the users information to a file; it writes fine, the program runs fine, however the writer doesn't write to the file in the desired way. I had noticed upon onpening the file it writes to, it leaves blank lines sometimes where I don't want it to and I can't see why. Below is the code relevant to the file writing (it is the only place in the file where the `filewriter` is used). All variables etc. have been defined and work properly.

```
    Details = "Name: " + name + " CardNo: " + CardNo + " Current Balance: " + balance + " overdraft? " + OverDraft + " OverDraftLimit: " + OverDraftLimit + " pin: " + PinToWrite;
    try{
        //Create writer to write to files.
        File file = new File(DirToWriteFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true); // **note second param?**
        Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8"));        
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("VirtualATM.txt");
        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String CurrentData = "";
        while((bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = CurrentData;
                bw.write(CurrentData);
                ((BufferedWriter) bw).newLine();
        }
        bw.write(Details);
        System.out.println("Account created!");

        System.out.println(name + " Your card number is: " + CardNo);
        //  close the reader.
        bufferedReader.close();
        //Close the writer.
        bw.close();
```

The desired output to the file is where there is no blank lines left anywhere in the file, the actual output to the file after writing to it a few times looks like the following:

[image: output the the file]

Comment: Always [flush your buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush()) after writing

Comment: @kolossus [closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close()) already flushes.

Comment: Your While loop is only writing new lines to file.

Comment: @Philipp-  Ah. I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code is wrong:

```
String CurrentData = "";
while((bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = CurrentData;
    bw.write(CurrentData);
    ((BufferedWriter) bw).newLine();
}
```

`CurrentData` (BTW, variables should start with lowercase) is always `""` (empty string), so you are writing nothing and then a new line character.

```
while((currentData=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {...}
```

should work

Comment: I've changed that, and it still is not writing as I'd like to, its output looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u87xjja06ly2yoo/Screenshot%202014-09-30%2016.06.51.png?dl=0

Comment: You need to add "\n" at the end of Details, or add a newLine after writing it to the file.

Comment: IS there any way I can stop it writing the same account more than once when it runs through the program again?

Comment: That's another question